# How to bring the answer of this binary multiplication code in binary?

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation, shift

```
int product = 0;
String num1 = "11100001";
String num2 = "10110001";
int multiplicand = Integer.parseInt(num1);
int multiplier = Integer.parseInt(num2);
for(int i=7; i>=0; i--) {
  if((multiplier & 01) != 0) {
    product=product+multiplicand;
  }
  multiplicand <<=1;
  multiplier >>=1;
}
System.out.println((product));
```

This is the code for binary multiplication. It has been asked about many times but I still have following confusion about this question:

- After the shifting operation,the binary result does not remain binary anymore. At the end the product variable is not binary. How do I don't let shifting affect the final result, so that the product is in binary? (In this specific example, the answer is 2115700113 which is clearly not a binary number.
- What does 01 mean in (multiplier & 01)?

Thanks for answer in advance.

Comment: Please format your code (indenting the bodies of your loops and conditions) - currently it's really hard to read.

Comment: The problem starts with `Integer.parseInt(num1)`. That gives a value of 11100001, which *isn't* the integer you want to parse... Fundamentally you need to understand that an `int` is just an `int`... it isn't "in" any particular base. That's only relevant when converting to text.

Comment: What do you suggest I should do instead of parsing? @JonSkeet

Comment: I suggest you parse it using a base of 2...

Comment: Now the value of product is 39825 @JonSkeet

Comment: So forgetting the binary part, what *numbers* are you trying to multiply and what result do you expect? Separate "binary representation" from multiplication.

Comment: Oh thanks @JonSkeet I got your point. In this example I was trying to multiply 225 with 177, and the result is 39825 indeed. Now I just need to convert it to binary representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Integer.parseInt("100101", 2);`
This will parse the integer as a binary number.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this as a last statement:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(product));
```

To see the binary version of your product.

Java prints out the numbers using decimal base numbers, since human is the master.
Internally in the memory, or CPU registry everything is binary.